# Problem Installing HP ProLiant Utilities on Ubuntu Server 20.04.3

Tags: server, hp

I am trying to install HP ProLiant Utilities on Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 I followed a guide I found online which was made for Ubuntu 18. But mine is Ubuntu 20.04.3. The steps i've done so far are as follows:

```
sudo echo "deb http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp bionic/current non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mcp.list

sudo curl http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpPublicKey1024.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo curl http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpPublicKey2048.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo curl http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpPublicKey2048_key1.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo curl http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpePublicKey2048_key1.pub | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update
```

All the above commands seem to run successfully and the final command I am supposed to run is this:

```
sudo apt install hp-health hponcfg amsd ams ssacli ssaducli ssa
```

But this command seems to fail with the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amsd : Depends: libjson-c3 (>= 0.10) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As a result of this final step, the tools are not installing. Can anyone please help? Could installing Ubuntu Server 18 instead of 20.04.3 solve the problem?

Comment: Was this the guide you were following?  https://blog.nathanv.me/posts/hp-utilities-ubuntu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manual visit of http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp shows that they [have repository](http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/) for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

So you can simply replace the *bionic* to *focal* in already added mcp.list file programmatically as follows:

```
sudo sed -i "s/bionic/focal/" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mcp.list
```

Then update package lists and install needed packages by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install hponcfg amsd ams ssacli ssaducli ssa
```

But please note that `hp-health` is not available via repo, so you can download and install it manually:

```
wget -c http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/pool/non-free/hp-health_10.80-1874.10_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./hp-health_10.80-1874.10_amd64.deb
```

Comment: In 22.04 this partly still works but you have to use `jammy` instead of `focal`.  It looks lke `hponcfg` and `ams` can no longer be installed this way either.